# Use of calc() inside fxFlex not working on edge

Tags: html, css, angular-material, microsoft-edge, angular-flex-layout

I've read that there's no way Edge works with calc() inside of a fxFlex. How can I make it work? Is there any workaround?

I want to show two inputs at same line with a gap of 10px. On chrome it does work, but not on Edge.

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="calc(50% - 10px)">
```

I've tried to use `<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="10px grid" fxLayoutAlign="center">` but doesnt work on edge either.

See at:
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/pull/667

Comment: which version of Microsoft Edge browser version are you using? Have you ever try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error or check the CSS style? According to [this link](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API) and [these demos](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/stackoverflow), I have created a sample on my side, it works well on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44 version), please check the demos. Besides, here is [another sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout), you could refer to it.

Comment: Found the problem. The problem was a matfield with a mat select. It was causing some problems. Now I fixed setting a max-width of container